# Apache Airflow command not found with SSHOperator

Tags: ssh, airflow

I am trying to use the SSHOperator to SSH into a remote machine and run an external application through the command line. I have setup the SSH connection via the admin page.

This section of code is used to define the commands and the SSH connection to the external machine.

```
sshHook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='remote_comp')
command_1 ="""
cd /files/232-065/Rans
bash run.sh
"""
```

Where 'run.sh' runs the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
starccm+ -batch run_export.java Rans_Model.sim
```

Which simply runs the commercial software starccm+ with some options I have specified.

This section defines the task:

```
    inlet_profile = SSHOperator(
        task_id='inlet_profile',
        ssh_hook=sshHook,
        command=command_1
)
```

I have confirmed the SSH connection works by giving a simple 'ls' command and checking the output.

The error that I get is:

```
bash run.sh, error: run.sh: line 2: starccm+: command not found
```

The command in 'run.sh' works when I am logged into the machine (it does not require a GUI). This makes me think that there is a problem with the SSH session and it is not the same as the one that Apache Airflow logs into, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with SSH connection (at least from the error message). However, the issue is with starccm+ installation path.

Please check the installation path of `starccm+` .

Check if the installation path is part of $PATH env variable

```sh
$ echo $PATH
```

If not, then install it in the standard locations like `/bin` or `/usr/bin` etc (provided they are included in `$PATH` variable), or export the installed director into PATH variable like this,

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/<absolute_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal but if you struggle with setting the path variable you can run starccm stating the full path like:

```
/directory/where/star/is/installed/starccm+ -batch run_export.java Rans_Model.sim
```